# How to scrape all rows from a dynamic table in html using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's link for scraping : http://5000best.com/websites/Games/

I tried almost everything I can. I'm a beginner in web scraping.

My code :

```
import requests
from  urllib.request import  urlopen
from urllib.error import  HTTPError
from urllib.error import  URLError
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import csv


try:
    html = urlopen("http://5000best.com/websites/Games/")

except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)

except URLError as u:
    print(u)

else:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    table = soup.findAll('div',{"id":"content"})[0]
    tr = table.findAll(['tr'])[0:]
    csvFile = open('games.csv','wt', newline='',encoding='utf-8')
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    try:   
        for cell in tr:
            th = cell.find_all('th')
            th_data = [col.text.strip('\n') for col in th]
            td = cell.find_all('td')
            row = [i.text.replace('\n','') for i in td]
            writer.writerow(th_data+row)      

    finally:   
        csvFile.close()
```

This code only scrape the first page of the table... I want all the pages.
I inspected the web page but I didn't saw any url changes while toggling the page numbers, So it's completely dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it directly using `pandas.read_html()` function as a `DataFrame` which will do it easily for you.

```py
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    for item in range(1, 4):
        df = pd.read_html(url.format(item))[1]
        print(df)


main("http://5000best.com/websites/Games/{}/")
```

Sample of output:

[image]

**CSV** edit:

```
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    for item in range(1, 4):
        df = pd.read_html(url.format(item))[1]
        print(f"Saving Page {item}")
        df.to_csv(f"page{item}.csv", index=False)


main("http://5000best.com/websites/Games/{}/")
```

Code updated for single `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    goal = []
    for item in range(1, 4):
        df = pd.read_html(url.format(item))[1]
        goal.append(df)
    final = pd.concat(goal)
    print(final)


main("http://5000best.com/websites/Games/{}/")
```

Comment: It's an easy way though... but it will scrape only first page of the table. As the table is paginated, I'm looking for a way to scrape all the paginated table data.

Comment: @HemantSah seems you didn't tried to run the code yet. be informed it's will paginate all tables. that's why i made a loop !

Comment: @ αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη , The more I see your solution the more fascinated I am.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib glad to help :)

Comment: @HemantSah I've updated the answer for you to save the `tables` within `csv` files.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη How can I make a single dataframe containing all the results. Can you help me with that.

Comment: @HemantSah you've then to edit your question and limit it to one specific point instead of going from one issue to another without showing any self effort taken !

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have come up with a solution, I want you to see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61765967/10347430 
Thanks for your help, I appreciate that.

Comment: @HemantSah you don't need all this big way. code updated for single data-frame. feel free to accept the answer if it's helped you by ticking the check-mark beside the answer.

Comment: I don't have any problem with your approach, I like because it's way simple. But I did what I was told to do. Can't argue with boss

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the network inspector for that page reveals that it makes requests to

- http://5000best.com/?w.c&xml=1&ta=9&p=1&sortby=0&ise=&h=01
- http://5000best.com/?w.c&xml=1&ta=9&p=2&sortby=0&ise=&h=02
- http://5000best.com/?w.c&xml=1&ta=9&p=3&sortby=0&ise=&h=03

when you change pages. You may want to just scrape those instead.

Comment: Is there any way to store all these links into list or dictionary automatically without inspecting every table.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to help you understand.

Have you used the developer tools in your browser? Open that (Use F12 or right click > inspect element) and select the network tab. Now while keeping the tab open, click on the next page link. A request shows up in the Network Tab.

This is what you are looking for. All dynamic thing on a web page can be viewed here.

Hope this helps you learn something. Cheers!

Comment: Is there any way to automate this to store all these links into list or dictionary. I want to scrape the table for all categories i.e. Games, Commerce, Music etc. OR do I have to store it manually..?

Comment: You can run 2 loops, one for each category, then inside this loop, run an iterative loop for each page. If the page you hit has no links at all, you may break the inner loop as this means you have reached the end of that category.

Comment: I didn't get it... I want to make a list of all these dynamic links from every category. Is this possible... OR do I have to store all these links by visiting every table by myself.