# How to scrape the dynamic table data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to scrape the table data from http://5000best.com/websites/

The content of the table is paginated upto several pages and are dynamic.
I want to scrape the table data for each category. I can scrape the table manually for each category but this is not what I want.

Please look at it and give me the approach to do it.
I am able to make links for each category i.e. http://5000best.com/websites/Movies/, http://5000best.com/websites/Games/ etc.
But I am not sure how to make it further to navigate through paginated table for each category.
And after making all the links I need to extract table data by using that links.

**Edit** : I am using requests, BeautifulSoup4,

Comment: What languages and frameworks are you wanting to work with? Ex: Python (requests, BeautifulSoup, selenium, etc.)

Comment: I am using request and BeautifulSoup. I don't know how to do this project with selenium. I just used request and BS to extract data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came with this approach to **scrape** tables from each category.

```
# ------------Hemant Sah--------------------

# <- --------Importing Libraries-------- ->
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import math
import itertools
import requests
import sqlalchemy
import re

final_list = []
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([])


def make_soup(url):
        
    try:
        html = requests.get(url)

    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(e)

    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml')
        # print(html.status_code)
    return soup

def get_categories_from_soup(soup):
    total_list = []
    for  item in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"sca2"}):
        total_list.append(item.text)
    for  item in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"sca2_a"}):
        total_list.append(item.text)
    for  item in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"sca2_b"}):
        total_list.append(item.text)
    for  item in soup.find_all('div',{"class":"sca2_c"}):
        total_list.append(item.text)            
    total_list.remove("All (5000)")
    total_list.remove("Porn (201)")
    return total_list

def make_url(total_list,url):
    path, page_num, test_page_num, modified_links, new_links = [],[],[],[],[]
    for category in total_list: 
        reg_exp_path = re.compile(r'^\w+')
        path.extend(reg_exp_path.findall(category))
        test_page_num.extend(re.findall('[0-9]+',category))
    # print(path)
    for c in test_page_num:
        temp = math.ceil(int(c)/100)
        page_num.append(temp)
    # print(page_num)        
    # print(page_num)
    for p in path:
        links= (url+p+"/")
        modified_links.append(links)
    # print(modified_links)    

    for w,p in zip(modified_links,page_num):
        for n in range(1,p+1):
            temp = w+str(n)
            new_links.append(temp)
    print(new_links)
    return new_links
        
def fetch_table_data(links):
    for l in links:
        soup = make_soup(l)
        my_table  = soup.find('table',{'id':'ttable'})
        rows = my_table.find_all('tr')
        for tr in rows:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [tr.text for tr in td]
            final_list.append(row)
        df = pd.DataFrame(final_list,columns=["Rank","Score","Category","Audience","URL","Links","blank","Desc"]) 
        print(df)    
    df = df.drop("blank", axis=1)
    # print(df)
    return df
    # df.to_csv('final_data.csv')    
      

def main():
    url = "http://5000best.com/websites/"
    soup = make_soup(url)
    total_list = get_categories_from_soup(soup)
    links = make_url(total_list, url)
    dataframe = fetch_table_data(links)
    
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Scrapy spider:

```
import scrapy

class Best500Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "best5000"
    start_urls = ['http://5000best.com/websites/1']

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.xpath('//table[@id="ttable"]//tr'):
            record = {}
            record["Rank"] = row.xpath('./td[1]/text()').get()
            record["Score"] = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get()
            record["Category"] = row.xpath('string(./td[3])').get()
            record["URL"] = row.xpath('string(./td[5])').get()
            yield record
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//div[@id="dpages"]/span[@class="pagen0"]/following-sibling::span[1]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page_url:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=response.urljoin(next_page_url),
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

i saw the site and to move to another page just add /pageNumber at the end of the link ,

For example 
http://5000best.com/websites/50 : will get you page 50

You can use this tool to get python requests code for one page and add a loop : https://curl.trillworks.com/

just put "curl http://5000best.com/websites/50" and adapt your code after

Comment: I want to create a program that stores all these links automatically.